# Configuring New Distributed Cache for Azure Websites Preview

Tags: azure

**UPDATE:** Nevermind I've found it. It's not done via the Azure Portal but inside the Azure Project Properties Dialog inside Visual Studio.

Anyone know where the **new** Distributed Cache Feature (I'm not talking about Azure AppFabric Cache) that [Scott mentioned in his post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/06/07/meet-the-new-windows-azure.aspx) can be configured for a website?

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980643/new-azure-distributed-cache-for-azure-websites-in-reserved-instance-mode

This is not supported with the current release.

Answer (score 2):

Adding information for those who may be wondering what is it:

Yes "Distributed Cache" is a instance specific feature which can be configured during development time with Windows Azure June SDK, via Role properties in Visual Studio as seen in this screen shot:

[image]

This feature is available only for Windows Azure Virtual Machine and roles but not for "Windows Azure websites (FREE) in Shared Mode".

Comment: Thanks. But what I still do not understand is how it is possible to apply those settings to an Azure Website (Preview) which seems to live in a implicit role that cannot be configured by the developer.

Answer (score 1):

The distribute cache is not available in the Azure Website Free or shared because you are not alone on your instance.  It should become possible on a reserved, but still not available.  Don't forget that the distribute cache is still in preview, so always evolving.